# How to convert float to half in GLSL?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader, opengl-es-3.0

How to convert vertex attributes' data type from **float** to **half** in GLSL with OpenGL ES 3.0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GLSL Half (floating point) attribute type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595137/glsl-half-floating-point-attribute-type)

Comment: Added a better OpenGL ES answer to the above; the existing desktop answers would have been incorrect.